# Bank deposit slip labeled "credit"

Tags: word-choice, terminology

I went to deposit a check into my bank account at a well known bank, and noticed there were no deposit slips to fill out the information. They had a different kind of slip labeled "credit" in large red words with "counter deposit." I went to the teller and informed him that I could not find a deposit slip, and he told me that the "credit" slip was indeed the correct slip to fill out for making deposits.

I am curious whether or not this terminology makes sense. In my mind, when I use a credit card, or take out a line of credit, I am borrowing money that I have to pay back. That seems completely different from depositing a check into a bank account. There is no borrowing or paying back, it's just the money going into an account.

Further, wouldn't the "counter" in "counter deposit" imply "against, in opposition" to making a deposit?

Answer (score 2):

When you pay a sum of money into your account, you are crediting your account with that sum. You are thinking of meaning (1) below; the meaning used on the bank slip is meaning (4)

> credit
>
> 1. uncountable noun
>      If you are allowed credit, you are allowed to pay for goods or services several weeks or months after you have received
>      them.
>      The group can't get credit to buy farming machinery.
>      You can
>      ask a dealer for a discount whether you pay cash or buy on credit.
> 2. uncountable noun
>      If someone or their bank account is in credit, their bank account has money in it. [mainly British]
>
>    The idea that I
>      could be charged when I'm in credit makes me very angry.
>      I made sure
>      the account stayed in credit.
>      Interest is payable on credit
>      balances.
> 3. verb
>      When a sum of money is credited to an account, the bank adds that sum of money to the total in the account.
>      She noticed that only
>      $80,000 had been credited to her account. 
>      The bank decided to change the way it credited payments to accounts.
> 4. countable noun
>      A credit is a sum of money which is added to an account.   The statement of total debits and credits is known as a
>      balance.

[Credit](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/credit)